# Rolling back Entity Framework changes if application crashes

Tags: sql, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

First, let me apologize in advance, I'm sure the answer to this exists somewhere, but after two hours of searching I decided to go ahead and present it here.

I have a C# Windows Forms application with Entity Framework 6.0.  The application migrates customer records from one database to another.  Let's simplify with this example: table [Device] has field [CustomerId], which is a key to [Customer].[Id], which is the identity column of that table.  This means in order to create the row in [Device], I must first add to [Customer] and call SaveChanges(), ao that the identity column will get seeded. so that I can assing [Device].[CustomerId].

The actual level of nesting is much more complex, i.e. Customer.Device.ScheduleMode.ScheduleEntry.DeviceConfiguration.

Hypothetical problem:
The migration could take 10-20 minutes, if the user's machine crashes in the middle of the work the DB could be corrupted (not as in it's totally broken but as in the customers' records are now in a 'broken' state).  We can't handle this issue in the code obviously (where's the event handler for OnSystemCrash btw? lol).

It seems logical that we could do something like declare a "batch," write the batchId to the file before starting the work.  Then after crash recovery take the batchId from the log file and use it to rollback the batch from SQL server.

Does any pattern like this exist, or can anybody suggest another way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

[Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)

It looks to me like you'll want to call `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` in a `using` block, and within that, perform all your work.  At the end, when the block runs out of things to do, call `Commit()`.

Within the `using` block, you can include a `try/catch`, and in the `catch` you can put a `Rollback()` command in case the overall operation fails.

Comment: In my experience, disposing the transaction doesn't commit it, but I might be wrong, it's been a while

Comment: @Jcl, you're right; the example on that page does use `Commit()`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is exactly what I needed.  Can't believe I've been using entity framework for 4 years without this.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, start a transaction (with `Database.BeginTransaction()`) then commit it (call `Commit()` on the returned object)  at end. If it's never commited it will never do any changes (in the event of a crash), and you can also purposedly roll it back.